# Native regular expressions used in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have been researching a lot and cannot find regular expressions that are used in CakePHP. The rule in question is the email validation.

Does anyone know which expression is used to validate email or knows where they can be found?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's there not to find?
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Utility/Validation.php#L448

Also, for CakeEmail and sending emails there is another rule:
https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/lib/Cake/Network/Email/CakeEmail.php#L323